# Redesign of Server architecture on Amazon AWS

Tags: architecture, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memcached

Our current architecture of a project is as below.
There are 2 amazon instances. Both has Ubuntu 10.10 installed on it.

**Instance 1:  (m1.large) --**
This instance has Php, Apache and MySql installed.
It contains main website + API (Developed in Php) + Database (MySql)

**Instance 2: (t1.micro) --**
This instance has Php, Apache and MySql installed.
It contains a Javascript.

**Client-Server Interaction:**
On client side, there is a block of JS code which loads JS file of **Instance 2** on client. This JS file creates request and sends it to API on **Instance 1**. 
API on instance 1 generates response and sends it to client.

On instance 1 there are cron processes which run on weekly basis, i.e. every Sunday for around 5-6 hrs.

Maximum CPU utilization on instance 1 is around 80% and on Sunday when cron is set to run, it goes above 95%.  Average request count per day on main instance is around 225k.

```
**There is no issue on instance 2 of CPU utilization.Size of database is 7.5 GB**
```

**Need of new Architecture:**
As we can see, in the current architecture the CPU Utilization is high. If we want to serve more requests, this architecture is not efficient. As our number of clients are increasing, number of requests on server  and database size will also increase.

Can you please suggest new architecture design? 
We are also planning to change our database from MySql to MongoDB. Also, separate Database from instance 1. Is this a right decision?

Can anyone please suggest any new technology which we can implement for the new architecture like Memcached, nginx etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link to one of Amazon's [Reference Architectures](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf) that may help:

[image]

In a nutshell:

- Split your infrastructure up into tiers (Web, App, Data)
- Use auto scaling groups to spin up/down as your traffic increases/decreases
- Split the tiers across Availability Zones for High Availability
- Use CloudFront to host static images/javascript/etc. for speed sensitive
  items

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but here are some points to consider:

- get your database off the app servers. You can use [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/en/rds/) for an Amazon hosted MySQL instance.
- Try to use a separate webserver for static resources. [nginx](http://nginx.org/) would be a good choice for that.
- nginx can also work as a frontend proxy to forward your dynamic PHP requests to your backend servers.
- This option also gives you easier scalability. If you need additional computation power, just add more backend PHP servers, add them to your nginx config and you are done.
- In your app, try to use a transparent cache layer connected to memcache (which should probably be installed on another instance). If a result is not found in cache, build it (for example by querying your database) and store it in the cache. Later requests can use the result from the cache then.

Answer (score 0):

Alright here are few things you might want to consider:

1. You need to know how many max consecutive request are you getting , instead of one day average request. you can improve and test the number of consecutive request dealt be apache by either setting up in apache.conf ( to some limit) and increasing the config of ec2 instance / using autoscaling . And as your cpu utilization is going up due to cron job on sunday, autoscaling on cpuutilization is the way to go.
2. You might consider using Cloudfront , it improves the performance ( as in retrieval time), and also make application highly available.
3. If you are planning to move to MongoDb, you won't be able to use RDS. If you stick to Mysql, you should use RDS.
4. While considering memcaching , try to implement caching on application level as well as database level, as memcache can give you some discrepancies.
5. Nginx is a good option to serve static content , and could act as a good proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Really good thoughts by the others here.  I figured I would chime in with regards to the static content, since the common theme in other answers was to use something like Nginx for this.  For me, I have found it much easier to places images, javascript, CSS, etc. into an S3 bucket and put a Cloudfront distribution, rather than having to even mess with trying to provide web servers for this content.  You can get your static content on edge nodes much closer to the end users, and not have to worry about any of the scaling aspects at all.

I would also recommend moving to newer version of Ubuntu (perhaps 12.04 from Canonical).

I would try to not run large cron processes (i.e. those consuming large amounts of CPU or disk cycles) on any of the actual production web servers.  Perhaps spin up an identical instance, not in your load balancer) as needed to perform these tasks.  This also you to size/scale your web servers appropriately (not for worst cases when cron is running)

Whether to use Mongo vs. MySQL really depends on your data structure (i.e is it better suited to relational structure, or schema-less structure).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I agree with @Mike Brant. Nice input by everyone here and the bottom line is -
“Whether to use Mongo vs. MySQL really depends on your data structure (i.e. is it better suited to relational structure, or schema-less structure).”
Regarding the static content issue, I think Nginx is a pretty good option but I wouldn’t rule out Cloudfront (mostly for lack of enough experience with it).But as for your database choice, if you go for NoSQL, I think [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a good choice, and if you go for MySQL I would suggest you also take a look at [Xeround](http://xeround.com/) in addition to RDS. Cheers :)